# Apache with LDAP not able to authenticate and forward

Tags: apache, ldap, haproxy, proxypass

I have Apache configured on a machine and proxy's to actual app, authorising using LDAP.

eg., form_auth.conf in Apache is like this

```
 <Location /myapp/home/j_security_check>
    ErrorDocument 401 /myapp/home/login.jsp
    AuthType form
    AuthName form_auth
    SetHandler form-login-handler
    LDAPReferrals Off
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://details"
    AuthLDAPBindDN “details"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword “a£456&89"
    AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation http://10.1.5.55:8080/myapp/
    Session On
    SessionCookieName mysession path=/
    SessionCryptoPassphrase secretpass
    SessionCryptoCipher aes128
    SessionMaxAge 1800
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
    Require valid-user
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthFormFakeBasicAuth On
</Location>
<LocationMatch "^/(myapp)">
        AuthFormProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPURL     "ldaps:details"          
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=UNIX TEST0 SZ Service Account,OU=Environments,OU=User,OU=Delegated,DC=test,DC=LOCAL"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "a£456&89"
        AuthType form
        AuthName form_auth
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation http://10.1.5.55/myapp/home/login.jsp
        Session On
        SessionCookieName mysession path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secretpass
        SessionCryptoCipher aes128
        SessionMaxAge 1800
        Require valid-user
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthFormFakeBasicAuth On
</LocationMatch>
ProxyPass /myapp http://10.1.5.55:8080/myapp max=480 retry=0 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://10.1.5.55:8080/myapp
```

Now from local machine I made a tunnel on port 9090 to Apache server on port 8080.

When in my browser I type "http://localhost:9090"

shows me Apache index.html page and I can see log on Apache server. When I try to access localhost:9090/myapp I can see browser url changed to  10.1.5.55:8080/myapp/home/login.jsp but no response and time out.

On Apache error logs - first URL to access Apache, my logs are like this

AH01502: headers: ap_headers_output_filter()

```
 [authz_core:debug] [pid 26517] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.6.1.10:55334] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[authz_core:debug] [pid 26517] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.6.1.10:55334] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted

[authz_core:debug] [pid 26517] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.6.1.10:55334] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[authz_core:debug] [pid 26517] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.6.1.10:55334] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

When I try to access myapp I get this log and time out

```
mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.6.1.10:55347] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)

[authz_core:debug] [pid 26518] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.6.1.10:55347] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)

[core:debug] [pid 26518] util_cookies.c(59): [client 10.6.1.10:55347] AH00007: ap_cookie: user '(null)' set cookie: 'myapp2session=3x/IdXV5SmKhepiUQ8kUSLw/6Dwv9vxc97x78JhsOZrGF2Tx8Y5TnH7uf0fOfI2+czX3ZB6m92dJSlMttrX1VA==;Max-Age=1800;path=/'

[headers:debug] [pid 26518] mod_headers.c(848): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()

[core:info] [pid 26514] [client 10.6.1.10:55348] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/myapp/home/login jsp
```

I get the form output displayed.

What's missing in my config, because this is a working config in different environment.